# pycurl.multicurl - Cant get my the returned results, only the object memory address

Tags: python, pycurl

I have been trying to get this example code working https://fragmentsofcode.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/pycurl-curlmulti-example/ for a bit tonight and it has me stumped (not difficult).

```
m = pycurl.CurlMulti()
for url in urllist:
    response = io.StringIO()
    handle = pycurl.Curl()
    handle.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    handle.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, response)
    req = (url, response)
    m.add_handle(handle)
    reqs.append(req)

# Perform multi-request.
# This code copied from pycurl docs, modified to explicitly
# set num_handles before the outer while loop.
SELECT_TIMEOUT = 1.0
num_handles = len(reqs)
while num_handles:
    ret = m.select(SELECT_TIMEOUT)
    if ret == -1:
            continue
    while 1:
            ret, num_handles = m.perform()
            if ret != pycurl.E_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM:
                    break

for req in reqs:
    # req[1].getvalue() contains response content
        print(req[1].getvalue())
```

I have tried the following prints

- req[1]
- req[1].getvalue()
- req[1].getvalue().decode('ISO-8859-1')

The closest I have come is printing something like the following for all fetched URL's

- _io.StringIO object at 0x7f19f931d9d8

I have also tried using io.BytesIO with the same results.

Comments in the code are from the original author, and I have changed some minor things that I think are version dependent, and removed the comments related.

How can I print the contents of the object at that memory address rather than just the address?

EDIT:
print(req[1].getvalue()) raises the following error

print(req[1].getalue())
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'getalue

so I squished it into variable like so

temp = req[1].getvalue()
print(temp)

and it just returned a b with single quotes like so:
b''

Comment: getvalue() should work, add your actual results to the question.

Comment: See also https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/examples/retriever-multi.py.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback D. SM
I have added the result of using getvalue() above.

Comment: Your exception message indicates you misspelled getvalue.

Comment: oh my!!
Thank you D. SM
I spent so much time making changes to this, I am sure I have deleted that simple line and retyped it multiple times. I almost refuse to believe that's been the issue the whole time, but the evidence is there for the internet to laugh at. Much appreciated